# ¿El lenguaje cambia/evoluciona en pro de la economía lingüística y la facilidad de comunicación?

Tags: historia

Como hablante nativo y curioso de la historia del idioma, he aprendido y notado que algunos cambios en el idioma, *por lo general*, responden a una lógica de economía y claridad. Por ejemplo, se adoptan algunos extranjerismos cuando estos suelen ser una forma más concisa para referirse a conceptos complejos, o directamente no existe una palabra en el idioma que represente una idea u objeto. O, con el tiempo, las frases para referirse a algo tienden a ser más cortas.

Sin embargo, en algunos debates en redes sociales sobre el uso del llamado lenguaje inclusivo, cuando expreso mi opinión al respecto, diciendo lo anteriormente mencionado, un contraargumento suele ser que los cambios en el idioma no son necesariamente así, de forma natural, sino que también ha habido cambios que se han hecho de forma arbitraria y/o forzada por algunas minorías.

¿En la historia del idioma, qué cambios han ocurrido de esta forma?

Comment: Hola, Gabriel, bienvenido al sitio. Si quieres extender tu pregunta a otros idiomas que no sean el español y hacerla de forma más genérica, me parecería una buena pregunta para formularla en [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), solo que tendrías que plantearla en inglés. Así podrías obtener ejemplos de cambios forzados en cualquier idioma.

Comment: Supongo que la mayoría de cambios empiezan en minorías. Un ejemplo reciente de cambio "forzado" es el cambio de "variante india" a "variante delta". "Forzado" solo significa que todos los periódicos empezaron a llamarla así y la gente se acostumbró.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is much too broad for this site.

Comment: Some questions are just to ...

Answer (score -1):

No creo sea ni una cosa ni la otra. Como todo en la vida, existen miles de variantes intermedias entre la economía lingüística y las arbitrariedades minoritarias.

En la pregunta no se hace referencia a las clases bajas, la falta de formación y los guetos marginales, cuando estos son los que mayor "aporte" han dado a la lengua española con el transcurso del tiempo. Personalmente, más que facilidad lo veo como **necesidad** de comunicación.

- En España es muy habitual escuchar *almóndiga* en lugar de
  *albóndiga*, por lo general por gente mayor o con escasa formación; aunque también cocineros en la TV lo suelen utilizar. La RAE (Real
  Academia Española) dice al respecto:

[image]

<sub>*[Enlace del tweet](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1176052353545453570/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1176052353545453570%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.es%2Fcultura%2Fabci-aceptado-almondiga-institucion-sirve-duda-bandeja-201909231239_noticia.html)*</sub>

- Sin caer en prejuicios, quien dice [*asín*](https://dle.rae.es/as%C3%ADn) en lugar de *así*
  queda bastante definido. Sin embargo la RAE lo incluye en su
  diccionario.

Solo por poner un par de ejemplos, pero hay miles de formas similares aceptadas y en uso. Personalmente veo a la RAE bastante más accesible que en años anteriores respecto a términos populares locales.

En Argentina, el conocido *lunfardo* surge de una mezcla entre los primeros inmigrantes, donde muchos de ellos sin saber hablar castellano correctamente, "creaban" palabras para comunicarse. Con el tiempo estas se hicieron de uso popular y su divulgación en gran parte ha sido favorecida por el destino que varios de ellos tenían después de un tiempo de desarraigo y necesidad de subsistir: la cárcel. Hay varios ejemplos de palabras del lunfardo que provienen de conversaciones entre los habitantes temporales de las dársenas de los puertos.

Muchas palabras que utilizamos hoy provienen no solo del lunfardo argentino, sino también del uso popular proveniente del la difusión masiva del lenguaje en las cárceles, punto de reunión en gran porcentaje de una vasta y rica en léxico, cultura marginal.

[Enlace con *lunfardismos* aceptados por la RAE.](http://geocities.ws/lunfa2000/drae.html)

Answer (score -1):

No *todo* el idioma se simplifica.

Hay que tener en cuenta que los idiomas no son bloques, sino que están formados por distintos "registros". El *español* que usas es una mezcla de variedades, y tú decides automáticamente cuál variedad usarás para hablar con tus amigos, tu hijo de 3 años, tu suegro, tus alumnos, tu público, etcétera.

Uno de esos registros, el lenguaje "informal" o "cotidiano", suele simplificarse o evolucionar hacia formas o significados "poco estrictos" con respecto a la norma, incluso con frecuencia a partir de los errores. Esta es la variedad más frecuente, y va llevando consigo al idioma hacia adelante en un cambio simplificador.

Por otro lado hay variedades que prefieren mantenerse apegadas a la norma, incluso a la forma de hablar que fue correcta en el pasado y ya no lo es. Un ejemplo es el español jurídico, por cierto muy pedante, que tarda siglos en cambiar. El lenguaje burocrático, de las ceremonias y formalidades sociales también cambia lentamente, dado que por su naturaleza intenta estandarizar el idioma, y a veces solo puede ser modificado por cambios en las leyes o reglamentos.

Y también hay una variedad de lenguaje que busca activamente hacerse más compleja. (Yo lo conocía en mis años de estudiante como *lenguaje hierático*, pero no lo pude encontrar ahora con ese nombre). Es el lenguaje que usamos cuando queremos hacer notar a los otros que formamos parte de una élite de iniciados, poseedores de algún conocimiento, valor o mensaje que el resto no tiene. Es el lenguaje de las religiones, ideologías políticas, pseudociencias y de algunas ramas del conocimiento, que dicen las cosas de una forma suficientemente compleja, extensa o rebuscada como para que no todos entiendan el mensaje o como para que se reconozca en el hablante a una especie de autoridad.

El lenguaje "inclusivo" (y digo esto a partir de mi oposición a él) es un mecanismo social que se usa para dar a entender a los demás que se forma parte del selecto grupo de las personas "buenas". Es un lenguaje que favorece mucho más al emisor del mensaje, al convertirlo en autoridad moral, que al referido, quien seguirá siendo abusado o pobre o discriminado aunque hayan cambiado las palabras con que se lo nombra.

Por ejemplo, en mi país Chile, puedes decirle a tu madre (usando el registro informal):

> Voy a ir a comer a la casa de unos amigos.

y ella va a entender perfectamente que los "amigos" no son todos necesariamente de sexo masculino. El grupo de amigos puede estar formado tanto por hombres como por mujeres y su género no es significativo.

Sin embargo, en una situación pública (usando el registro formal) eso actualmente sería imperdonable. "Debes" decir

> Voy a ir a comer a la casa de un amigo y una amiga.

a menos que ambos sean hombres. Esto complejiza y extiende el mensaje de una forma que racionalmente calificaríamos de innecesaria y torpe. Pero hay que comprender que esa "entropía negativa" se debe a que el lenguaje en este caso se ha vuelto más difícil *para* que quede claro al auditorio que el hablante forma parte del grupo de las personas que exigen trato justo a las mujeres.

Comment: Concuerdo. No trato de empaquetar a todo el idioma en la misma bolsa. Editaré la pregunta para evitar la generalización.

Comment: lo de "Voy a ir a comer a la casa de un amigo y una amiga" le agrega complejidad innecesaria.